# 405 Method not allowed in koa-router

Tags: node.js, routes, koa, http-status-code-405, koa-router

I am getting 405 Method Not Found as response when using PUT and DELETE request using POSTMAN.
My `app.js` file looks like this

```
 const Koa = require('koa');
 const serve = require('koa-static');
 const cors = require('@koa/cors');
 const userRouter = require('./routes/users');
 const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 var app = new Koa();
 app.use(serve(__dirname + '/view'));
 app.use(cors());
 app.use(userRouter.routes());
 app.use(userRouter.allowedMethods());
 app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(port);
 });
```

and my `./routes/users` file looks something like this

```
     router.get('/users/:id', getData)
              .post('/users', postData)
              .put('/users/:id', updateData)
              .del('/users/:id', deleteData);
```

Also when I check response headers section in POSTMAN it shows

```
  Allow →HEAD, GET
  Connection →keep-alive
  Content-Length →18
  Content-Type →text/plain; charset=utf-8
  Date →Thu, 15 Feb 2018 05:25:36 GMT
  Vary →Origin
```

I've also tried all the possible solutions out there on internet and git issues but still no use
Please help me fix this.

Comment: Hmm, would need to see more of your code. Could you share your main `app.js` file?

Comment: @saadq Here is the `app.js` file
`const Koa = require('koa');const serve = require('koa-static');const userRouter = require('./routes/users');const port = 3000;var app = new Koa();app.use(serve(__dirname + '/view'));
app.use(userRouter.routes());app.use(userRouter.allowedMethods();app.listen(port, () => {console.log(port);});`
Here is the `./routes/users` file
`const router = require('koa-router')();const body = require('koa-body');router.get('/users/:id', getData).post('/users', insertData).put('/users/:id', updateData).del('/users/:id', deleteData);`

Comment: @saadq Please bear with this, I had to remove all spacings because comments had a limit of characters but these are the files

Comment: **.put('/users/:id', updateData)** method shouldn't have **/:id** it is same as post method accepts body.

Comment: @sultan we can use it

Comment: @ShrinathPrabhu how you solve the problem? I am getting the same while calling the PUT request

Comment: @chetanmekha  Have u solve it?  I met this today.

Comment: @JackChouMine Yes, we resolved it with help of setting proxy and working good.